# Which heroku email add-ons support gmail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send emails from my app. I have tried sendgrid before but for some reason it was not sending email for gmail. 
Here is my configuration.

```
config.app_domain = 'unstarv.herokuapp.com'

# Email
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: config.app_domain }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
port: '587',
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: 'someuser',
password: 'somepass',
authentication: :plain,
domain: 'unstarv.herokuapp.com'
```

}

Is it enough configuration to send gmail emails for heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any smtp client that supports their authorization scheme should in theory allow you to send mail through gmail. In terms of Heroku addons you don't really need anything beyond the standard rails ActionMailer class. Using the standard mailer will also keep your code more portable should you choose to run it somewhere besides Heroku.

Comment: I did use sendgrid. And I sent many emails but only one of them I receive. It took also so much time just to receive that one email . Is there a way to make the email send right away in Rails 4.1.8 ?

Comment: if it gets out of your app then it's left to the email routing and delivery gods and it's out of your hands.

Comment: Great !! So do I have to even use an add-on ?

Comment: Do I have to use an add-on or not ?

Comment: you do not need any addons to send mail

Comment: for future readers to consider  - I would avoid using SendGrid add-ons to heroku - it is expensive, and i don't see any benefit that you get vs simply rolling your own. just handle the smtp credentials in a config file and voila: you're sending emails

Comment: @BKSpurgeon do you know of an example repo on github that demonstrates how to do this? It would be great to see a working example.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/benkoshy/3cb1cb2aafd420142e8dfd5fc05ad3a9

Answer (score -1):

When you say "support Gmail", do you mean sending email to Gmail...or sending via Gmail? (I'm assuming the former, since you said "...not sending email for gmail...").

There is a new [Heroku Beta Add-on from Sparkpost.com](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sparkpost)

There are several [Heroku Email/SMS Add-Ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#email-sms) available, but Sparkpost is the most advanced/flexible email infrastructure service amongst the offerings listed.

[@kevinkimball](https://github.com/kevinkimball) created a [SparkPost Ruby Gem on Github](https://github.com/kevinkimball/sparkpost_rails/tree/master).